# Custom Value Picker

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am facing the following issue. On the VF page wizard at step 3 I am not able to implement the following functionality .Do you have some suggestions ?

1. the ability to use a date picker for date field
2. the ability to use search for a look up field
3. or even my own custom value picker

VF page

```
  <!-- for this page to work with a specific custom object, change standController="entityname" to custom object api name  
    For example, if custom object name is Warehouse__c, change first part of the first line to standardController="warehouse__c" -->

  <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.UtilJS}" />
  <apex:form id="wizard">

  <apex:sectionHeader title="Mass Update Wizard" subtitle="Step {!step} of 5"/>

      <apex:pageBlock id="step1" title="Step 1. Confirm records to be updated" mode="edit" rendered="{!step='1'}">
            <apex:pagemessages escape="false"></apex:pagemessages>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:pageBlockTable var="a" value="{!selected}">
                <apex:column value="{!a.Subject}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.CaseNumber}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Account.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Status}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Owner.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
            </apex:panelGrid>
          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
              <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Previous"/>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!step2}" value="Next"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock> 

      <apex:pageBlock id="field" title="Step 2. Specify the field to be udpated" mode="edit" rendered="{!step='2'}">
          <apex:pagemessages escape="false"></apex:pagemessages>
          <apex:selectList id="pickList" size="1" value="{!fieldName}" required="true">
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!fieldTypeOptions}"/>
          </apex:selectList>
          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
              <apex:commandButton action="{!step3}" value="Next"/>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" onclick="return confirmCancel()" immediate="true" style="margin-left: 2em"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock> 

      <apex:pageBlock id="step3" title="Step 3. Specify the new value for field - {!fieldName}" mode="edit" rendered="{!step='3'}">
         <apex:pagemessages escape="false"></apex:pagemessages>
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='CURRENCY'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='DATE'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='DATETIME'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='TEXT'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='NUMBER'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='COMBOBOX'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='DOUBLE'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='EMAIL'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='ID'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='INTEGER'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='PERCENT'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='MULTIPICKLIST'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='PHONE'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='STRING'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='REFERENCE'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='BASE64'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputTextArea rendered="{!fieldType='TEXTAREA'}" rows="15" cols="100" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputCheckBox rendered="{!fieldType='BOOLEAN'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:selectList rendered="{!fieldType='PICKLIST'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" size="1">
         <apex:selectOptions value="{!picklistvalues}"/>
         </apex:selectList>
             <apex:pageBlockButtons >
              <apex:commandButton action="{!step2}" value="Previous"/>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!step4}" value="Next"/>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" onclick="return confirmCancel()" immediate="true" style="margin-left: 2em"/>
             </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock> 

      <apex:pageBlock id="step4" title="Step 4. Confirmation" mode="edit" rendered="{!step='4'}">
          <apex:pagemessages escape="false"></apex:pagemessages>
          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
              <apex:commandButton action="{!step3}" value="Previous"/>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!step5}" value="Update"/>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" onclick="return confirmCancel()" immediate="true" style="margin-left: 2em"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock> 


      <apex:pageBlock id="step5" title="Step 5. Results" mode="edit" rendered="{!step='5'}">
          <apex:pagemessages escape="false"></apex:pagemessages>
          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
              <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Done"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock> 

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
/**


public with sharing class MassUpdateSimpleController {

   private final ApexPages.StandardSetController cntr;
   private final PageReference fromPage;
   private final List<SObject> objs;
   private Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap;
   private transient ApexPages.Message currentMsg;
   private final String newLine ='<br></br>';
   private Schema.SObjectField field;
   private String sType;
   private Object convertedFieldData;
   private List<SelectOption> picklistValues;
   private String currentStep;


   public MassUpdateSimpleController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
       currentStep = '1';
       controller.setPageSize(1000);
       cntr = (ApexPages.StandardSetController)controller;
       fromPage = cntr.cancel();
       if (this.objs == null) {
            this.objs = (List<SObject>)cntr.getSelected();
       }
       if (getRecordSize()<1) {
            String msg = 'No record was selected on the list view.  Please click Previous button and select records for mass update.'; 
            currentMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, msg);
       } else {
            sType= discoverSObjectType(objs.get(0)).getName(); 
            String msg = 'Number of records selected for update: ' + getRecordSize(); 
            currentMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, msg);
       }
       ApexPages.addMessage(currentMsg);


   }


   /* public MassUpdateSimpleController() {
       System.debug('ids: ' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ids'));
       selected = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id0');
       return; 
       cntr = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(objs);
       fromPage = cntr.cancel();
       if (this.objs == null) {
            this.objs = (List<SObject>)cntr.getSelected();
       }
       if (getRecordSize()<1) {
            String msg = 'No record was selected on the list view.  Please click Previous button and select records for mass update.'; 
            currentMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, msg);
       } else {
            sType= discoverSObjectType(objs.get(0)).getName(); 
            String msg = 'Number of records selected for update: ' + getRecordSize(); 
            currentMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, msg);
       }
       ApexPages.addMessage(currentMsg);
   } */


    public String getStep() {
        return currentStep;
    }

    public String getsType() {
        return sType;
    }      

    public integer getRecordSize() {
     if (objs!=null) {
        return objs.size();
     } else {
        return 0;
     }
    }

    public String filterId {
        get;
        set;    
    }


    public String getNow(Boolean bShowTime) {
        DateTime now = DateTime.now();
        if (bShowTime)
            return  now.year() + '-' + now.month()+ '-' + now.day()+' '+now.hour()+ ':' +now.minute() + ':' + now.second();
        else
            return  now.year() + '-' + now.month()+ '-' + now.day();
    }

    public List<SObject> objsToUpdate {
        get {
            return (List<SObject>) cntr.getSelected();
        }
        set;
    }

    public String valueToUpdate {
        get;
        set;    
    }

    public String fieldName {
        get;
        set {
            fieldName=value;
            field = fieldMap.get(value);
            fieldType = field.getDescribe().getType().name();
        }   
    }

    public String fieldType{
        get;
        set;    
    }

    private Object convertUserInputToFieldData(){
        if (field==null) return null;
        DisplayType t = field.getDescribe().getType();
        Object s = null;

        try {       
                if (t==DisplayType.Double||t==DisplayType.Currency || t==DisplayType.Integer || t==DisplayType.Percent){
                    s = decimal.valueOf((String)valueToupdate);         
                } else if (t==DisplayType.Boolean){                 
                    if (valueToUpdate=='true'){
                        s = true;               
                    } else if (valueToUpdate=='false'){
                        s = false;              
                    } else {
                        s = Boolean.valueOf(valueToUpdate);
                    }
                } else if (t==DisplayType.Date) {
                    s = Date.valueOf(valueToUpdate);
                } else if (t==DisplayType.DateTime) {
                    s = DateTime.valueOf(valueToUpdate);
                } else if ((t==DisplayType.PickList || t==DisplayType.PickList) && valueToUpdate==null) {
                    s = '';
                }else {
                    s = valueToupdate;
                }
        } catch (System.TypeException e){
            System.debug('Type exception: ' + e.getMessage());
            currentMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }  

        return s;
    }


    public String getFieldInfoToDisplay() {
        if (field==null) return '';
        String msg = 'Field type of selected field: ' + fieldType + newline;

        Schema.DescribeFieldResult d = field.getDescribe();

        if (d.getType()==DisplayType.TextArea || d.getType()==(DisplayType.String)||d.getType()==(DisplayType.URL)) {
            msg += 'Max lengh: ' + d.getLength();
            valueToUpdate='';
        } else if (d.getType()==DisplayType.DateTime ){
            msg += 'Format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss';
            valueToUpdate=getNow(true);
        } else if (d.getType()==DisplayType.Date){
            msg += 'Format: yyyy-MM-dd';
            valueToUpdate=getNow(false);
        } else if (d.getType()==DisplayType.Picklist){

            picklistValues = new List<SelectOption>();      
            if (d.isNillable()) {
                picklistValues.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
            }
            for (Schema.PicklistEntry p : d.getPickListValues()) {
                picklistValues.add(new SelectOption(p.getValue(), p.getLabel()));
            }
            msg += newline + 'Please select a picklist value';
        } else if (d.getType()==DisplayType.MultiPicklist){

            msg += 'Valid Picklist Values: ';
            String combined ='';

            for (Schema.PicklistEntry p : d.getPickListValues()) {
                msg += newLine + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>' +p.getValue()+'</b>';
                combined += p.getValue()+';';
            }
            msg += newline + 'Use ; to seperate each picklist value you want to select';
            msg += newline + 'For example, to select all the picklist values, enter <b>' + combined + '</b> in the textbox below to select all picklist values';
        } else if (d.getType()==DisplayType.Integer){
            msg += 'Max digits: ' + d.getDigits();
        } else if (d.getType()==DisplayType.String){
            msg += 'Max length: ' + d.getLength();
        } else if (d.getType()==DisplayType.Double || d.getType()==DisplayType.Currency || d.getType()==DisplayType.Percent){
            msg += 'Format: (' + (d.getPrecision()-d.getScale()) + ','+d.getScale() +')';
        } else if (d.getType()==DisplayType.Reference){
            msg += 'Use this to change selected records to reference a different record, or even dereference records if the filed is left blank' + newLine;
            msg += 'Please enter ' + d.getName() + ' that the selected records should reference to';
        }

        return msg;
    }


    public PageReference cancel() {
        return fromPage;
    }

    public PageReference step1() { 
        currentStep='1';         
        return ApexPages.currentPage();
    }

    public PageReference step2() {
        if(getRecordSize()<1) return fromPage;      
        currentStep='2';         
        return ApexPages.currentPage();
    }

    public PageReference step3() {
        currentMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, getFieldInfoToDisplay());
        ApexPages.addMessage(currentMsg);
        currentStep='3';         
        return ApexPages.currentPage();
    } 

    public PageReference step4() {
        convertedFieldData = convertUserInputToFieldData();

        // data type validation
        if (currentMsg!=null) {
            ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, getFieldInfoToDisplay());
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
            ApexPages.addMessage(currentMsg);
            return ApexPages.currentPage();
        }

        String msg = 'Please review your selections before confirm: <br></br>'; 
        msg = msg + '<br><b>Records Selected:</b>    ' + getRecordSize() +'</br>';
        msg = msg + '<br><b>Field To Be Updated:</b> ' + fieldName + '</br>';
        msg = msg + '<br><b>New Value:</b>           ' + convertedFieldData + '</br>';
        currentMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, msg);
        ApexPages.addMessage(currentMsg);
        currentStep='4';         
        return ApexPages.currentPage();
    } 

    public PageReference step5() {
        currentMsg = (new MassUpdater(objs, field, convertedFieldData)).massUpdate();
        ApexPages.addMessage(currentMsg);
        currentStep='5';         
        return ApexPages.currentPage();
    }

    public DescribeSObjectResult discoverSObjectType(SObject s) {
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> des = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

        for(Schema.SObjectType o:des.values()) {
            if( s.getSObjectType()==o) {
                return o.getDescribe();
            }     
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getFieldTypeOptions() {
        // prevent url hacking
        if (objs.size()<1) return null;

        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();      
        options.add(new SelectOption('','-None-'));

        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sObj = discoverSObjectType(objs.get(0));

        fieldMap = sObj.fields.getMap();

        List<String> keys = sortByFieldLabel(fieldMap);

        for(String key:keys) {
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult d = fieldMap.get(key).getDescribe();

            if(d.isAccessible() && d.isUpdateable()) {
                if (isSupportedFieldType(d)) {
                    String label = d.getLabel();
                    if(d.isCustom()) label += ' (' + key +  ')';
                    options.add(new SelectOption(key, label));
                }
            }
        }
        return options;
    }


    public List<SelectOption> getFieldTypeOptionsCase() {

        String key;
        // prevent url hacking
        if (objs.size()<1) return null;

        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();      
        options.add(new SelectOption('','-None-'));

        Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Account.AccountNumber.getDescribe();
            options.add(new SelectOption(f.getName(),f.getLabel()));    

        return options;
    }

    private List<String> sortByFieldLabel(Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> gd) {
        List<String> keys = new List<String>();

        Map<String, List<String>> labelMap = new Map<String, List<String>>();

        for(Schema.SObjectField s:gd.values()) {
            String label = s.getDescribe().getLabel();
            if(labelMap.get(label) == null) {
                labelMap.put(label, new List<String>());
            }

            labelMap.get(label).add(s.getDescribe().getName());        
        }

        List<String> labels = new List<String>(labelMap.keySet());
        labels.sort();

        for(String label:labels){
            keys.addAll(labelMap.get(label));
        }

        return keys;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getPicklistValues() {
        return picklistValues;
    }

    private boolean isSupportedFieldType(DescribeFieldResult d) {
        // always return true for now, but in future some fields might not be supported
        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

To get a native functionality of salesforce.com like a datepicker or a lookup search popup window you need to use `apex:inputField` components of the visualforce:

[Visualforce input fields](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm)

As of winter 14 release you can use `apex:input` field type for this purpose (for this you need to set the API Version to 29):

[apex:input](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_input.htm)

Comment: I have already tried what you said. I am getting apex:inputField can only be used with SObjects/objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable. as you see from the controller I still want to use  {!valueToUpdate}

Comment: @buni try to use `apex:input`