# Need help editing this VF page so it will respect apex-input for reference field

Tags: visualforce, field-update

I am new here and trying to stick to guidelines by posting a new question instead of in an answer :)

My issue is exactly the same as this issue:
[Custom Value Picker](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18118/custom-value-picker?newreg=8fd72bf98a81447ba8b69c278ff78c0d)

Meaning that I have installed the "Mass Update And Mass Edit From List View" package from AppExchange and had the same trouble where if I use it to edit a Lookup or Master-Detail field it won't use the native salesforce lookup tool and force me to enter a salesforce ID instead.

To be specific I am not able to implement the following functionality by editing the VF page wizard at step 3:

- the ability to use a date picker for date/date-time field
- the ability to use search for a look up field

I read what @mast0r wrote:

> To get a native functionality of salesforce.com like a datepicker or a
>   lookup search popup window you need to use apex:inputField components
>   of the visualforce:
>
> Visualforce input fields
>
> As of winter 14 release you can use apex:input field type for this
>   purpose (for this you need to set the API Version to 29):
>
> apex:input

So I have changed the Visualforce page to API Version 29, changed the code from

```
apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='REFERENCE'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}"
```

to

```
apex:input rendered="{!fieldType='REFERENCE'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}"
```

However it still just gave me the text field and I didn't see date picker or the lookip tool. The controller is still on API version 14 as I can't change it. (Maybe I need to brute force it by coding it in a sandbox again?)

The modified VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="KH_Order__c" recordSetvar="unused" extensions="MassUpdateSimpleController" id="page" docType="html-5.0">

  <!-- for this page to work with a specific custom object, change standController="entityname" to custom object api name  
    For example, if custom object name is Warehouse__c, change first part of the first line to standardController="warehouse__c" -->

  <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.UtilJS}" />
  <apex:form id="wizard">

  <apex:sectionHeader title="Mass Update Wizard" subtitle="Step {!step} of 5"/>

      <apex:pageBlock id="step1" title="Step 1. Confirm records to be updated" mode="edit" rendered="{!step='1'}">
            <apex:pagemessages escape="false"></apex:pagemessages>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:pageBlockTable var="a" value="{!selected}">
                <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Order_Status_auto__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Village__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Order_Date__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Sanitation_Teacher__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.LBO__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
              <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Previous"/>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!step2}" value="Next"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock> 

      <apex:pageBlock id="field" title="Step 2. Specify the field to be updated" mode="edit" rendered="{!step='2'}">
          <apex:pagemessages escape="false"></apex:pagemessages>
          <apex:selectList id="pickList" size="1" value="{!fieldName}" required="true">
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!fieldTypeOptions}"/>
          </apex:selectList>
          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
              <apex:commandButton action="{!step3}" value="Next"/>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" onclick="return confirmCancel()" immediate="true" style="margin-left: 2em"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock> 

      <apex:pageBlock id="step3" title="Step 3. Specify the new value for field - {!fieldName}" mode="edit" rendered="{!step='3'}">
         <apex:pagemessages escape="false"></apex:pagemessages>
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='CURRENCY'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:input rendered="{!fieldType='DATE'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:input rendered="{!fieldType='DATETIME'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='TEXT'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='NUMBER'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='COMBOBOX'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='DOUBLE'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='EMAIL'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='ID'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='INTEGER'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='PERCENT'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='MULTIPICKLIST'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='PHONE'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='STRING'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:input rendered="{!fieldType='REFERENCE'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputText rendered="{!fieldType='BASE64'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputTextArea rendered="{!fieldType='TEXTAREA'}" rows="15" cols="100" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:inputCheckBox rendered="{!fieldType='BOOLEAN'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" />
         <apex:selectList rendered="{!fieldType='PICKLIST'}" value="{!valueToUpdate}" size="1">
         <apex:selectOptions value="{!picklistvalues}"/>
         </apex:selectList>
             <apex:pageBlockButtons >
              <apex:commandButton action="{!step2}" value="Previous"/>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!step4}" value="Next"/>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" onclick="return confirmCancel()" immediate="true" style="margin-left: 2em"/>
             </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock> 

      <apex:pageBlock id="step4" title="Step 4. Confirmation" mode="edit" rendered="{!step='4'}">
          <apex:pagemessages escape="false"></apex:pagemessages>
          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
              <apex:commandButton action="{!step3}" value="Previous"/>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!step5}" value="Update"/>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" onclick="return confirmCancel()" immediate="true" style="margin-left: 2em"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock> 


      <apex:pageBlock id="step5" title="Step 5. Results" mode="edit" rendered="{!step='5'}">
          <apex:pagemessages escape="false"></apex:pagemessages>
          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
              <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Done"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock> 

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Thank you in advance,
Gordon

Comment: Unfortunately because of the way the Mass Edit and Update page is written there is not an easy fix to this other than rewriting the controller. The only way to get the automatic lookup rendering is to use an `apex:inputField`, however this won't work in this case because the `valueToUpdate` property on the controller is simply a string and not an sObject field and so the page is unable to determine what type it is. Thankfully the Mass Edit and Update package is unmanaged so you could modify the controller if you wanted, but it wouldn't be a small undertaking (the code is a bit messy).

Comment: Thank you very much Alex! That makes sense to me. Fortunately my immediate task allow me to get around that (I just need a button to edit the one lookup field). So in fact by using this I am overkilling it, when I have the chance I will try to pare this down - or better yet, write a proper controller from the start.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to add date picker functionality in vf page

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="Sample">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            Date: <apex:input type="date" value="{!dat}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public class Sample {
public Date dat {get;set;}
public Sample() {

}
 public Date fDate { get; set; }

}
```

Please let me know if this helps you.